# On duplicating an Xcode product. Why is the name red, and how can I change the name?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I am trying to duplicate an Xcode target (Xcode 4.3.2) in order to make a free version of my iPhone App.

In Xcode, I have selected the old target, right clicked, and then "duplicated". As a result, I got `myapp copy.app` and `myapp copy-info.plist`.

However, the name `myapp copy.app` is printed in **red** (even after the build). I guess it indicates that the file is missing!

Question 1: How can I solve the above problem?

Question 2: How can I change the name of the new target?

Comment: I answered a minute ago but I mis-read what your issue was, so I removed that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the .app file becomes active (not red in color) only when you build for device. Change your build setting to iOS Device instead of simulator and you should see a .app created inside the Debug-iphoneos folder in the Build directory. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

I can answer Question 2. You can change the target name from the project editor. Select your project from the project navigator on the left side of the project window to open the project window. Select the target from the target list on the left side of the project editor. Press the Return key to rename the target.

Unfortunately when you rename the target, Xcode doesn't rename related files, such as the info.plist file. You're going to have to rename the info.plist file using the file inspector. You also have to rename the scheme Xcode created for the target. Click on the Scheme menu in the toolbar and choose Manage Schemes to rename the scheme.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have renamed those files but I have the feeling that I have missed something since the new product is printed in red.

Answer (score 3):

After duplicating the target:

1. Select the target
2. Go to "Build Settings" in the right hand panel
3. In the "Packaging" section, rename the product name and the Info.pList file
4. In the file explorer, rename the pList to match that set in 3

Comment: Seems to me this answers the "how do I change the name" part of the question, which is what I needed, and it worked. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I too had an issue with red .app files in the Products folder.  I tried many of the remedies offered, but none worked. My particular issue may have been different.  If you have the same symptoms, my solution might work for you too.

### Symptoms

1. Red .app files in the Products folder in the Navigator area (left section of xcode)
   [image: Symptom 1]
2. When selecting the .app, the Utility area (right section of xcode) the File inspector view the “Full Path” displays:

   /Users/[user name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug/[app name].app
   [image: Symptom 2]
3. The app file is located at *(note the -iphoneos after Debug)*:

   /Users/[user name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[app name].app
4. Select the following:

   a. the project in the Navigator area (left section of xcode) (Symptom 4 - A)

   b. the project in the Editor area (middle section of xcode) (Symptom 4 - B)

   c. “Build Settings” tab (Symptom 4 - C)

Search for “Per-configuration Build Products Path” (Symptom 4 - D). The value is `build/Debug` instead of `build/Debug-iphoneos`.[image: Symptom 4]

### Solution

1. Select the following:

   a. the project in the Navigator area (left section of xcode) (Solution 1 - A)

   b. the project in the Editor area (middle section of xcode) (Solution 1 - B)

   c. “Build Settings” tab (Solution 1 - C)
2. Set the value of “Base SDK” to `Latest iOS (iOS 6.0)`.  Actually any of the iOS options should work. (Solution 1 - D)
3. Set the value of “Architectures” to `Standard (armv7, armv7s)`. (Solution 1 - E)
4. Set the value of “Supported Platforms” to `iOS` (Solution 1 - F)
   [image: Solution 1]

### Notice

1. The value for Per-configuration Build Products Path – Debug  is build/Debug-iphoneos (Solution 1 - G)
2. The .app files are no longer red. (Solution 1 – H)
3. The “Full Path” for the .app is:

   /Users/[user name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[app name].app